# js spread operator for module exports

Tags: javascript

How can I make this a one liner with the spread operator:

```
const module = extractVuexModule( Activities )

export const state = module.state
export const getters = module.getters
export const mutations = module.mutations
export const actions = module.actions
```

Comment: You can't, in any way.

Comment: I think you can make that code a one liner, but not using spread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports):

```
export const { state, getters, mutations, actions } = extractVuexModule(Activities);
```